# code assistance - how to bootstrap and plot paths with a mixed model

Tags: r, bootstrap

I created an Arima (3,1,1) model using the steps below. I was able to create a nonparametric model, but now I would like bootstrap for the created model (model 3). Also I'd like to plot the paths of the various simulations. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to R and this is my first question, so apologies in advance for lack of clarity, simplicity of question, etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#Creating Arima (3,1,1) model

data$Log.Spread1 <- as.zoo(data$Log.Spread) #changing variable log.spread into zoo ts
model3 <- auto.arima(data$Log.Spread1) #creating model from spread data
plot(forecast(model3, h=78, bootstrap = TRUE)) #forecasting ahead using arima model

#Nonparametric bootstrap

x <- data$Log.Spread1
n <- length(x)
B <- 100
resamples <- matrix(sample(x, n*B, replace = TRUE), B, n)
medians <- apply(resamples, 1, median)
sd(medians)
quantile(medians, c(.025, .975))

#Bootstrap using model?

#Graphing simulated paths?
```